# How do you convert Google Drive Java SDK objects to JSON?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have a bunch of Google drive objects and I want to make a MapDB of them. But in order to do that, they need to be serializable. And unfortunately... many google drive objects aren't serializable *sad face*

Example: `com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Group`

If you try to store that object in MapDB, no dice because it's not serializable.

How should I go about serializing these objects? Is there a to JSON / from JSON utility I need to know about?

UPDATE: It looks like toString gets the JSON. but how to load the string back later?

Comment: user `GSON` lib

Comment: OK trying that now

Comment: OK using GSON seems to work fine. no errors. i also already have faster jackson in the codebase might use that too. glad they are json friendly objects